# enumerateChildNodesWithName anomaly?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

If I do this (see below) it searches the entire node tree and lists all the TRIANGLE nodes:

```
   [rootNode enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"//TRIANGLE" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"BLOCK: %@", [node name]);
   }];
```

if I specify SPHERE as the start point and use "TRIANGLE" as a child match I get nothing?

```
   [sphereNode enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"TRIANGLE" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"BLOCK: %@", [node name]);
    }];
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

[image]

## EDIT:

sphereNode is not nil:

```
Printing description of sphereNode:
<SKNode> name:'SPHERE' position:{0, 0} accumulatedFrame:{{inf, inf}, {inf, inf}}
```

But your `[sphereNode inParentHierarchy:triangleNode];` suggestion does show `NO`, not sure why it should be in there, I will have a dig and see what I find. Much appreciated, thats certainly the problem.

Comment: Is it significant that you have "//TRIANGLE" in the first call and "TRIANGLE" in the second?

Comment: That is the psuedo-regex SpriteKit uses for this, which looks fine. Two things to check: make sure triangle in in sphere's hierarchy using `inParentHierarchy:`. Also (which you probably already tested), make sure sphereNode is valid and not nil.

Comment: Thank you Matt, as I mentioned in the edit the triangles are not showing in the hierarchy, I will have a look and remember this for the future. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a note, you have your `inParentHierarchy:` backwards, so that may not actually be the problem sadly.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, its still NO, now I am happy its still not working :) What it is doing is picking up another node called SPHERE which does not have any TRIANGLE children. This is only a test to see how things work, but I can see a few possible issues and having unique names for parents is going to be something thats going to help. Thanks again.